# Compiling Python module using IBM CPLEX Optimization into an exe file with customizable CPLEX path

Tags: python, runtime-error, cplex, auto-py-to-exe

I have developed a Python module that utilizes the IBM CPLEX Optimization library. I am currently using `auto-py-to-exe` to compile this module into an executable (exe) file. However, I need to allow users to specify the path to their own custom CPLEX Optimization installation directory.

Is there a method or approach that enables users to set the path to their individual CPLEX Optimization installation directory when compiling the Python module into an exe file using auto-py-to-exe?

I have used auto-py-to-exe to compile my module on my PC, and when I try to run it on the machine itself, I encounter the error: 'No Cplex runtime'.